# Does iPad 2 support for Core Spotlight?

Tags: ios, ipad-2, corespotlight

My iPad 2 has iOS 9.3.2 but still `Core Spotlight` doesn't work.

Want to know whether it is supported or not?

Comment: I found, Core Spotlight is not supported on iPhone 4s, iPad 2, iPad (3rd generation), iPad mini, and iPod touch (5th generation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/index.html) :

> NOTE
>
> Although app search is available in iOS 9 and later, the search functionality of NSUserActivity and Core Spotlight is not supported on iPhone 4s, iPad 2, iPad (3rd generation), iPad mini, and iPod touch (5th generation).